# How do i get flask to reload correctly using a docker host mount?

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose

How do i get flask to reload correctly inside a docker volumes host mount?

I have the following flask app and docker-compose file

```
---
services:

  flask:
    image: domain/my-flask:latest
    environment:
      - FLASK_DEBUG=1
    volumes:
     - "server.py:/app/server.py"
```

With a hello world flask app of:

```
from flask import Flask
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

print('Change Me')

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'

app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

Currently a change of 'change me' to 'was changed', i see 'change me' output.

On a third change, i will see the 'was changed'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to understand is that when you create a volume mount from a single file from your host into a container, you're essentially mapping the explicit inode of the file to the container. Many editors such as vim or pycharm use swap files that copy working files on top of the target file -- changing their inode id. For the most consistent results the following is recommended:

1: Turn off "use safe write" in editors like vim or pycharm.

2: Mount a target directory instead of a single file.

3: Set ENV variable: PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 (This instructs Docker not to buffer the output from Python in the standard output buffer)

4: Install Werkzeug watchdog. This is a more performant inotify based listener that will be run by flask if its installed on the system.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
---
services:

  flask:
    image: domain/my-flask:latest
    environment:
      - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
      - FLASK_ENV=development
      - FLASK_DEBUG=1
    volumes:
     - ".:/app"      #you can replace '.' with a full dir path
```

**requirements.txt**

```
watchdog==0.9.0
Werkzeug==0.15.2
```